# How to read Treatment values from split GO SDK

Tags: go, feature-flags

My split.io feature flag is `sky_name`

feature flag has following treatment
{
"sk_price":"45788"
}

I want to read `sk_price` when treatment is on.

My sample code is as below

```
import (
    "github.com/splitio/go-client/v6/splitio/client"
    "github.com/splitio/go-client/v6/splitio/conf"
)

func main() {
    cfg := conf.Default()
    factory, err := client.NewSplitFactory("YOUR_SDK_TYPE_API_KEY", cfg)
    if err != nil {
        
    }

    client := factory.Client()

    err = client.BlockUntilReady(10)
    if err != nil {
       
    }

    treatment := client.Treatment("CUSTOMER_ID", "sky_name", nil)
    if treatment == "on" {

// I want to get the "sk_price" value here when the treatment is on

    } else if treatment == "off" {
        
    } else {
       
    }
}
```

Comment: [You should not *force* a tag into your title.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) Because the tags appear below the question and tags are indexed by search engines along with the content of your question, you can trust that other people will be able to find your question based on tags they follow or search for.